# Wamp Server 2.4 avoids to show PHP 5.4 notices

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver, error-reporting

I have the following setting at my `php.ini` located at **`D:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin`**:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

I now have changed it to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

Then I restarted all services of Wamp.

It doesn't still show the the notices that the production server show.

At both states, in `phpinfo()` I can see `error_reporting` set to `32767`.

Comment: Is it reporting to a file instead of to the buffer?

Comment: It's not reporting to a file. When I want to check `PHP error log` from a sub menu at the tray bar's WAMP server's icon, I can see that the file doesn't even exist.

Comment: Why are they trying to close the question?!

Comment: The community is attempting to reach a consensus that this question is more suitable for the experts at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there was a little bug that escaped in WampServer2.4 and that was that the php.ini file had the `error_log` parameter commented out.

So edit php.ini ( using the wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini )

Look for

```
;error_log = "c:/wamp/logs/php_error.log"
```

and change it to

```
error_log = "c:/wamp/logs/php_error.log"
```

Assuming you are installed on the `C:` drive

Also check

```
log_errors = On
```

just to be sure.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't still catches PHP `notice`s.

Comment: Maybe you are just not generating any!

Comment: Yes, my friend, I am. I tried to call some undefined properties, and didn't get an `undefined` notice at all.